# Form Data not submitting complete string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Could someone tell me what my form data's string ends at the comma? I'm sending a form with react with a string with `foo, bar` but only `foo` is sent in the form data. This has nothing to do with the database as in the chrome dev tools, under network, I see only one value of the string. Here's a image of my actual views:

[image]

Only `Wordpress,` gets submitted. Noticed the `,`?

Some code, in React (I'm using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)):

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <Select ref="stateSelect" options={skillsOptions} simpleValue multi={this.state.multi} value={this.state.skillsSelectValue} name="skills" onChange={this.skillsUpdateValue} valueKey="value" labelKey="name" loadOptions={this.getContributors} />
</form>

skillsUpdateValue: function(newValueCnd) {
  // var str = newValueCnd.split(',');
  this.setState({
    skillsSelectValue: newValueCnd
  });

  this.setState({
   skills: newValueCnd
  });
},
```

Am I missing something from the `form`? Using just Rails, all words great.

**Edit:**

[image]
[image]

**Input options:**

```
var skillsOptions = [
    { value: 'one', name: 'One' },
    { value: 'two', name: 'Two' }
];
```

Comment: It's not clear what is happening.  What is the screenshot of?  Where in the code are you when you get that response?  What did you expect to get?

Comment: @gravityplanx The screen shot is of my chrome browser. I have a submit button, not in example. I expect to see `skills: Wordpress,Spree Commerce` as a form data.

Comment: Is that not exactly what it shows?

Comment: Nope. Only `Wordpress`

Comment: I noticed it in what you said it should be as well...  You said "I expect to see `skills: Wordpress,Spree Commerce`, and that is what you are indeed getting....

Comment: I need to save `Wordpress,Spree Commerece` in the db. Im only getting Wordpress.

Comment: Is your server receiving both params?  You need to trace the data to the point of failure.  Whatever the issue is, it's not related to the code you provided here, so there's not much anyone can do to help.  Track down the section where the data becomes incorrect and post that (if you can't figure out how to fix it yourself).

Comment: Yes I receive all other params no problem but having issue with the `skills` params. I'll post the logs and see.

Comment: @gravityplanx I have added two more images. Now only Spree Commerce gets in the form data, no Wordpress. Seems only one value can be selected. Why I get two `skills`?

Comment: Unless you post the code, I can't help you.  You've verified that you have the elements when in your react component, but your rails server is not receiving them.  So where's the code that shows the connection between those components?

Comment: Ok. I have not included the `getInitialState` as that's standard information. I am concerned about the `skillsOptions`. See post

Comment: Ok! Had a read through the docs of the module and it states to use `joinValues` so all is well. Thanks for your time! Problem solved.